# How to unit test "request.form" in python using pytest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I have a function which has a 'request.form' in an if condition and upon testing it,I have found that the statements below them are missing statements. This is a snippet from the function
function snippet

```
    if 'industry' in request.form:
        industry_sele = request.form['industry']
        country_sele = request.form['country']
        size_sele = request.form['size']

        if not request.form.get('open'):
            filters['open'] = False
            if 'open' in status_list:
                status_list.remove('open')
        if not request.form.get('assign'):
            filters['assign'] = False
            if 'allocated' in status_list:
                status_list.remove('allocated')
        if not request.form.get('closed'):
            filters['closed'] = False
            if 'converted' in status_list:
                status_list.remove('converted')
            if 'not converted' in status_list:
                status_list.remove('not converted')
```

All lines after "if 'industry' in request.form:" are missing when I check the coverage using `python3 -m pytest --cov-report term-missing --cov=projfolder/`
This is how I have written the unit test case. test_function.py

```
    def test_get_list_csv_manager(self):
        with self.client.session_transaction() as session:
            session['role'] = 'manager'
            session['id'] = 2
        res = self.client.get("/getListCSV", follow_redirects=True)
        self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
```

This piece of unit testcode runs successfully but doesn't cover the block of code which is above. How do I unit test request.form? Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I found an answer to this piece of code. What I did was wrote two seperate functions which would handle the two if statements.

```
    def test_request_form_csv(self):
        with self.client.session_transaction() as session:
            session['role'] = 'user'
            session['id'] = 1
        r = self.client.get('/getListCSV', data={'industry': 'All', 'country': 'UK', 'size': 'All'})
        self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)

    def test_request_args_opened(self):
        with self.client.session_transaction() as session:
            session['role'] = 'user'
            session['id'] = 1
        r = self.client.get('/getListCSV',
                            query_string={'industry': 'Compliance', 'country': 'USA', 'size': 'Midsize', 'open': False, 'assign': False,
                                          'closed': False})
        self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)
```

And those got my testcases covered.